# TYPO3 using markers with conditions

Tags: typo3, tt-news, typo3-8.7.x

There are some markers in my template. Sometimes markers can be empty, can I catch this situation? Something like:

```
if !###NEWS_IMAGE###
```

Comment: No. The marker/subpart based "template engine" is/was a simple search & replace thing without logical functions.
Maybe, you can migrate to EXT:news.

Comment: In the old days stdWrap offered many possibilities. Maybe there is a suitable TypoScript property ... e.g. `noImage_stdWrap`

Answer (score 1):

Markers or Subparts have no logic in the template.

All logic has to be done while generating the replacement text.
IN PHP you can use the usual PHP control structures.

if you fill the markers with Typoscript you can use the options of `stdWrap.if` to fill in any replacement string, even an empty string.

---

in this way you can condition label to show only if the value is set:

```
marks {
    something = TEXT
    something.field = title

    something.wrap = the title is |
    something.wrap.if.isTrue.field = title

    something.ifEmpty = no title given
}
```